# delegate method not getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios6, delegates, xcode4.5

I have looked at all the other questions with the same problem but I cannot seem to get my heard around it. I am pretty sure I have done everything correctly as this is not my first time using delegates.

```
//PDFView.h
@class PDFView;

@protocol PDFViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)trialwithPOints:(PDFView*)pdfview;
@end

@interface PDFView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PDFViewDelegate> delegate;
```

In the implementation file i am trying to call the delegate method from touchesMoved delegate of view

```
//PDFView.m
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.delegate trialwithPOints:self];
}
```

The class where the delegate method is implemented

```
//points.h
#import "PDFView.h"
@interface points : NSObject <PDFViewDelegate>

//points.m

//this is where the delegate is set
- (id)init
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{   
      pdfView = [[PDFView alloc]init];
      pdfView.delegate = self;

}
 return self;
 }

-(void)trialwithPOints:(PDFView *)pdf
{
    NSLog(@"THE DELEGATE METHOD CALLED TO PASS THE POINTS TO THE CLIENT");
}
```

So this is how i have written my delegate and somehow the delegate is nil and the delegate method is never called.

At the moment I am not doing anything with the delegate, I just want to see it working.

Any advices on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate?

Comment: sorry i edited my code.. i forgot to copy the code where i set the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you did not hold the reference to the instance of the delegate, and it got released because it is declared `weak`. You might be doing this:

```
pdfView.delegate = [[points alloc] init];
```

which you should fix to something like:

```
_points = [[points alloc] init];
pdfView.delegate = _points;
```

where `_points` is instance variable.

Comment: that was very helpful :). i indeed overlooked that.